# Regular expression to extract everything between two tags

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a few million custom txt files generated with content like this in each one of them.
I previously used ruby(Nokogiri) to parse through these files one by one and extract the contents from these files and store in the database.

```
    <doc id="12" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=12" title="Anarchism">
     ...
     ...
     ...
      few hundred lines of text
     ...

     </doc>
```

However using ruby seems to be too slow as it takes more than two weeks of running this single process to complete the overwhelming number of these article files. So I was trying to extract the data needed from the shell commands itself and skip ruby totally. But I am still a naive at using regular expressions.

So far I have been able to extract these data.

```
     informations=`grep -E '<doc' F1.txt`
     id=`echo $informations | grep -Po '\bid="[0-9]+"' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'`
     url=`echo $informations | grep -Po 'https?:\/\/(.*?)([A-Za-z]|[.]|[\/]|[?]|[=]|[0-9])*'`
     title=`echo $informations | grep -Po '(?<=title=").*(?=">)'`
```

But I also need to capture everything in between the doc tag as body.

```
     body=`a command to take those few hundreed lines between the two doc tags`.
```

I tried to use this in the grep environment  /(?<=">)(.)*(?=</doc>)/m .
`grep -Po '(?<=">)(.)*(?=<\/doc>)' F1.txt`
But it does not return any match.
Any suggestions on how to get this done ?

Comment: HTML *should* not be handled by regexen. Have you tried using a proper HTML parser? A well optimised script should be able to easily handle this without taking several weeks.

Comment: I tried with NokoGiri but just the massive amount of files to be opened and parsed might be the reason that it took so much of time.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<doc.*?</doc>
```

**UPDATE**:

```
 grep -P '<doc(.|\n)*?</doc>' file.txt
```

use -P option

Comment: grep '<doc.*?</doc>' F1.txt show nothing. I already did that.

Comment: why the down-vote! I just said that it worked for me with notepad++, so he can use it if he wants to.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/<doc/,/<\/doc>/' YourFile
```

Will stop at first  match